# introduce latency between ec2 instances

Tags: networking, amazon-ec2, cassandra

I have a 2nodes Cassandra ring on ec2 (10.96.31.143, 10.254.94.177) in the same zone (east-1). How can I introduce a 3 seconds delay for all cassandra-related network communications between them? I found 'dummynet' via Google as a possible solution but I haven't been able to figure a way.

Comment: This probably belongs on Serverfault, but the normal way on Linux would be with the network emulator queuing discipline. http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/netem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use tc. Check out the link for a pretty good write up of how to use it

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-traffic-shaping-using-tc-to-control-http-traffic/